# Fetch Many to Many collection using Hibernate Criteria

Tags: java, hibernate

I have two entities User and Attribute and they have Many to Many relation. like below.

```
public class User implements java.io.Serializable {

private Set<Attribute> attributes = new HashSet<>();

@ManyToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name = "user_attributes", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "user_id") }, 
           inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "attribute_id") })
public Set<Attribute> getAttributes() {
    return attributes;
}
```

}

User_Attributes table may or may not contain data. I am trying to fetch user like below

```
public User getUserByUserNameAndStatus(String userName, int status) {
    Criteria criteria = getSession().createCriteria(User.class);
    criteria.createAlias("attributes", "attr", JoinType.LEFT_OUTER_JOIN);
    criteria.setFetchMode("roles", FetchMode.JOIN);
    criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("attr.status", 1));
    criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("userName", userName));
    criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("status", status));
    User user = (User) criteria.uniqueResult();
    return user;
}
```

This code return me user object only if there is an entry in User_Attributes table otherwise it is returning me null. But what I want to fetch user object also if there is no entry in User_Attributes table.

Comment: You added a Restriction that attr.status has to be 1. When there are no attributes this restriction can hardly be fullfilled and therefor users without attributes don't match your query criteria. You could try using an or Restriction: attr.status is equal to 1 or attr is null.

Comment: Thanks it worked..